# How to use sum function in where condition using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Hello I am trying to make a query where I need to pass sum function in where conditions. Below is the query.

```
$this->Transaction->virtualFields['total_amount'] = 'sum(total_amount)';
$this->paginate = array('conditions'=>$conditions,'order' => 'Transaction.title ASC', 'limit' => '15','group'=>'Transaction.order_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with with model name

```
$this->Transaction->virtualFields['total_amount'] = 'sum(total_amount)';
```

Change it to

```
$this->Transaction->virtualFields['total_amount'] = 'sum(Transaction.total_amount)';
```

Comment: what is difference between your code and my code it is same. because Transaction model not bind with any other model that's why here is no need for 'Transaction.total_amount'. it is work with total_amount also